# Is it correct to say "this book is worth the acquisition"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Can you please advise whether or not grammatically and meaningfully correct to say "this book is worth the acquisition" when you find a book relevant and want to buy.

Comment: It's not particularly idiomatic. Standard phrasing is to say something useful / of value is ***worth having***. Or ***worth the [asking] price*** in contexts where it's important that it be ***good value** [for the money]* as well as useful.

Comment: (This book is worth having ) right ?

Comment: Yes, *This book is worth having* means the speaker thinks it's a good idea for you (and/or him) to have the book, with no implications for whether the price (if any) is "reasonable". But with *This book **is worth it***, the pronoun would usually refer to the ***price***, so that would imply it's being offered for a good / fair price. In unusual circumstances, "it" might refer to, say, the effort or time to be spent ***reading*** the book, so speaker would be saying it would be a good use of your time to read the book.

Comment: I think it's reasonable, though a hair stuffy sounding.

Comment: A Google search for  << "worth the acquisition" -cost -fort -self >> (I didn't look for further filters) doesn't give an encouragingly large number of hits. 18, as per page 2.  Grammatical, but inadvisable (quirky unnecessary choices seldom curry favour). Unidiomatic. In violation of a Gricean maxim.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).